# How to correct logic in comments View?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I build comments functional for post but has bug. When someone comment post, another user see correct comment body, but incorrect image and

```
def p(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    #user_that_text_comment = User.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, pk=pk)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    comment = Comments.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.creator = user
            comment.save()
            comment = Comments.objects.create(
                body=form.cleaned_data.get('body'),
                creator=user,

            )
            return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post, 'topic': topic, 'comment': comment, 'form': form})
    else:
        form = CustomCommentForm()
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post, 'topic': topic, 'comment': comment, 'form': form})
```

I builded comment function for post but it has bug. When someone comment post, another user see correct comment body, but incorrect image and name. 
i know why i has this problem(i suppose), it happend because i use `user=request.user`. Notice on string that i comment on 3 line. I was think that will help me,but it isn't. I use primary key in my url. `url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),` and when i use primary key in `filter` it return to me user that has same pk as post pk. I need that it return to me username and picture of user that create this comment.

Html template:

```
<div class="detailBox">
    <div class="titleBox">
      <label>{{topic.subject}}</label>
        <!--<button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>-->
    </div>
    <div class="commentBox">
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ topic.image.url }}" alt="">
        <p class="taskDescription">{{ post.message|safe|linebreaks}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="actionBox">

        <ul class="commentList">
            {% for comment in post.comment.all %}
            <li>

                <div class="commenterImage">
                  {% if user.profile.profile_img %}
                    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ user.profile.profile_img.url }}" >
                    {{ user.username }}
                    {% else  %}
                    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/no-translate-detected_1053-593.jpg">
                    {{ user.username }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="commentText">

                    <p class="">{{ comment.body }}</p> <span class="date sub-text">{{comment.created_at}}</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}

        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token%}
            {{form}}

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>{% endblock %}
```

Comment: show your html template, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `comment` prefix and relate to the `creator` to the variables inside the comment

```
    <li>

        <div class="commenterImage">
          {% if comment.creator.profile.profile_img %}
           <!-- ^^^^^   -->
            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ comment.creator.profile.profile_img.url }}" >
                                       <!-- ^^^^^   -->
            {{ comment.creator.username }}
              <!-- ^^^^^   -->
            {% else  %}
            <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/no-translate-detected_1053-593.jpg">
            {{ user.username }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="commentText">

            <p class="">{{ comment.body }}</p> <span class="date sub-text">{{comment.created_at}}</span>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Really? i was never think about this. Thank you so much!

Comment: glad to help you!